# ZF2 return $this->redirect()->toRoute(...) does NOT work on a Web server, only works on Localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, zend-framework2, webserver

I have been struggling with this issue for over a month now and nothing seems to help :((((
That's why I've decided to post here.

I have a ZF2 application which looks like this:
(on the web hosting)
root(www.exam.example.com - the subdomain points to /public)
So:

```
root
   config/
   module/
      Administration/
         config/
            module.config.php
         src/
         view/
         Module.php
   public/
      css/
      js/
      img/
      .htaccess(which has the RewriteEngine On)
      index.php
   vendor/
      ...
```

The problem is that when I'm on the localhost(same doc structure), the **return $this->redirect()->toRoute('products/default', array('action' => 'create'))** works just fine!
On the other hand, when the projects gets uploaded on the Web hosting, it DOES NOT WORK AT ALL, it leaves the page blank, never redirects.

I know there are a few posts here about this kind of issue, but the suggestions there does not work for me.

I'm thinking it might be something with the hosting configuration and the fact that the subdomain points to /public but I don't know.

Here are some details:

My module.config.php file: (router)

```
<?php

namespace Administration;

return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Administration\Controller\Products' => 'Administration\Controller\ProductsController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'products' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/products',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Administration\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Products',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:action][/:id]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Administration\Controller',
                            'controller'    => 'Products',
                            'action'        => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

My Controller: (ProductsController.php(just the createAction))

```
    class ProductsController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function createAction()
    {
        // Getting the ID(Type of the Product to create)!!!
        $productType = (int)$this->params()->fromRoute('id'); 

        if($productType > 0 && $productType < 4) {
            // Defining the Form depending on what type is the desired product...
            $form = $this->defineForm($productType);
            // Instantiate the Product with a type of whatever it is
            $product = new Product($productType);

            // Getting the type of the request - POST or GET
            $request = $this->getRequest(); 
            // Getting the service manager to have access to the configuration
            $sm = $this->getServiceLocator(); 
            // Getting the table which can interact with DB
            $table = $this->getProductsTable(); 
            $imgTable = $this->getImagesTable();

            if($request->isPost())
            {
                // Getting the post request data
                $postRequestData = $request->getPost()->toArray(); 
                // Getting the uploaded files
                $postRequestUploadedFiles = $request->getFiles()->toArray(); 
                // Merging the files uploaded with the rest of the data.
                $mergedData = array_merge($postRequestData, $postRequestUploadedFiles); 
                // Setting the input filter to filter the form fields.
                $form->setInputFilter($product->getInputFilter());
                // Filling in the post request data into the form to check then if it is valid depending on the input.
                $form->setData($postRequestData);

                // Checking form validity...
                if($form->isValid())
                {
                    $data = $form->getData();
                    $adapter = $this->getHttpAdapter();

                    $product->exchangeArray($data);
                    $date = date('Y-m-d');
                    $product->setDatePublished($date);
                    $savedProduct = $table->saveProduct($product);
                    if($savedProduct)
                    {
                        $imagesArray = array();
                        foreach ($postRequestUploadedFiles['images'] as $image)
                        {
                            if(!empty($image['tmp_name']) && substr($image['type'],0,5) == 'image')
                            {
                                $name = $image['name'];
                                $imageData = file_get_contents($image['tmp_name']);
                                $imageType = $image['type'];
                                $img = new Image($name, $imageData, $imageType);
                                $img->setRelation($savedProduct['id']);
                                array_push($imagesArray, $img);
                            }
                        }
                        $imgTable->saveImages($imagesArray);
                        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('products');
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('products/default', array('action' => 'create'));
                    }
                }
            }

            return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form, 'type' => $productType));
        } 
        else {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('products');
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be HIGHLY APPRECIATED!!!

Thanks

**EDIT**
I've managed to solve this. I don't know why it happened but apparently there was something missing within the core framework files. After re-installing the core it started working :)))
If anyone has this problem, well you can use my way to deal with it :D

Comment: if the page gets blank this indicates a server error/php fatal error, what does the debug network tab show as ``response code`` when the page gets blank? did you check your php error log?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled on the web host?

Comment: The mod_rewrite is enabled on the web host. 
The Network tab shows that the request is OK - 
Request Method:POST
Status Code: 200 OK

Answer (score 0):

turn error_reporting on on your public/index.php using:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
at the start of the page .. 
and check your problem again, you may get some helper info.

Comment: Nothing is shown, I've set the error_reporting in the index.php file but there is nothing on the page or in the error_logs :(

Comment: open view source of the resulting page and see if it contains anything ?
And try to remove the redirect to see if the site will work without it .. to be able to know if the problem in the redirect or it's in your confiuration